# Why does my Ajax call not retrieve the requested value ?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have various products in a drop down list. If I change the product, then the price changes and the line cost changes commensurate with the quantities being ordered.

**Problem:** When I select a product, an Ajax call is made to my DB. The correct `price` is returned. All good. When I choose an alternative product from the drop down, the product ID and it's var `value` changes correctly. However,instead of returning the new correct price, `price`shows the value from the previous query. That is to say, it appears that either the `price` is being cached, or the array`data[0].price` is not being cleared or the Ajax call is failing. I do not believe that the Ajax call is failing, as if I make then a further product change, I get a new result, BUT, *again* the `price` value from the query preceding it.  Bottom line, my `price` is always one query behind. I have tried using `cache:false` but that has made difference. I also tried setting the length of the variable `result` to 0, that just delivered an `undefined` error.

```
 $(".product_id").on('change', function() {                      //THIS GETS THE VALUE OF A PRODUCT FROM THE DB

   var value = parseFloat($(this).val()); // product_id
   var row =  $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".cost");
   var rowPrice = $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".price");

    // then we use the product_id to grab the price using AJAX //
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'product_prices/' + value,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var result = data[0].price;
                var price = Number(result);  //.toFixed(2);
                row.data('price', price); // store the row's current price in memory
                rowPrice.val(price); // allocate the price to the location called rowPrice
        }
    });

   var quantity = $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".quantity").val();

    if (quantity > 0){
        var price = row.data('price');
        var cost = (price * quantity);
        cost = Number(cost); //.toFixed(2);
        var displaycost =  $.formatNumber(cost,{format:"#,###.00",locale:"ca"});
        row.val(displaycost);

        var subTotal = 0;
        $("input.cost").each(function(){
            var ic = $(this).val();
            if (ic !==''){
                var inputCost = parseFloat(ic.replace(/,/g, ''));
                subTotal += inputCost;}
        });

        var discount_percent = $("#discount").val();
        if(discount_percent ==""){
            discount_percent = 0;
        }
        var calculations = newCalculate(subTotal, discount_percent);
        setValues(calculations, $("#updateValues"));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, meaning the callback function that you provide for it, is only executed later. In your case this means that this statement:

```
row.data('price', price);
```

is executed later (asynchronously) than this one:

```
var price = row.data('price');
```

...which indeed means you set the `price` to the previously retrieved value.

To avoid that, you'll probably want to move most of your code into the `success` callback function provided to `$.ajax()`, so that it only gets executed when you actually have received the data with the price.

Comment: Did this work out for you? Could you let me know?